# WP7 WrapPanel & MVVM

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to populate the Silverlight toolkit's `WrapPanel` via binding to an `ObservableCollection`? All the examples I've seen so far, including the toolkit example itself, either populate the `WrapPanel` programmatically or by explicitly adding each item in XAML.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**: Following [Geert van Horrik's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591096/wp7-wrappanel-mvvm/4591490#4591490) I tried using an `ItemsControl` to load the `WrapPanel` via binding. This is the XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Height="440"
              Margin="0,12,0,0">

  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectionContent}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>

        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                CornerRadius="4"
                BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush}">

          <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="OnWrapPanelTapped"
                                     DoubleTap="OnWrapPanelDoubleTapped" />
          </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>

          <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                 MaxHeight="48"
                 MaxWidth="48"
                 Margin="16" />
        </Border>

      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

`SelectionContent` is an `ObservableCollection` present in this `UserControl`'s code behind. It consists of `SelectionItem` object, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and exposes 2 public properties - `ImageSource` and `BorderBrush`.

I'm setting the `DataContext` for the `UserControl` in its constructor to `SelectionContent`. But this isn't working and the `WrapPanel` does not display anything.

Comment: You should check your output window. It will show binding errors. If you set the DataContext to "SelectionContent", you can't set the ItemsSource to "SelectionContent" again. If you want to set the DataContext to "SelectionContent" (I'd prefer a view model, but that's my opinion), use ItemsSource="{Binding}" (which binds to the current DataContext, which is "SelectionContent").

Comment: Brilliant! That was it, setting both to SelectionContent was indeed the problem, I set ` ItemsSource="{Binding}"` and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an ItemsControl. Then, you can set the WrapPanel as items panel.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <WrapPanel />
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I followed your advice but can't seem to get it working. Please take a look at my edited question. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you need that WrapPanel enclosed in an ItemsPanelTemplate